# ios OpenCV increases the image size

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

Below is code for converting `UIImage` to `cv::Mat`

```
+ (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image {

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols, rows;

    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        cols = image.size.height;
        rows = image.size.width;
    } else {
        cols = image.size.width;
        rows = image.size.height;
    }

    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels    
    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,             // Pointer to backing data
                                                cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                8,                          // Bits per component
                                                cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    cv::Mat cvMatTest;
    cv::transpose(cvMat, cvMatTest);

    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    } else {
        return cvMat;       
    }
    cvMat.release();    
    cv::flip(cvMatTest, cvMatTest, 1);
    return cvMatTest;
}
```

And this code for `cv::Mat` to `UIImage`

```
+ (UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat {

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize() * cvMat.total()];    
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                     // Width
                                    cvMat.rows,                                     // Height
                                    8,                                              // Bits per component
                                    8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                           // Bits per pixel
                                    cvMat.step[0],                                  // Bytes per row
                                    colorSpace,                                     // Colorspace
                                    kCGImageAlphaNone | kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,  // Bitmap info flags
                                    provider,                                       // CGDataProviderRef
                                    NULL,                                           // Decode
                                    false,                                          // Should interpolate
                                    kCGRenderingIntentDefault);                     // Intent

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);    
    return image;
}
```

I convert a 1080*1920 (1.5 mb) of image  to `cv::Mat` after some preprocessing i convert it to `UIImage` which gives me image of size 2517 * 1527(6 mb)

I don't want to increase the image size even after image processing. Please guide me where i am doing wrong

//Crop Action

```
 cv::Mat undistorted = cv::Mat( cvSize(maxWidth,maxHeight), CV_8UC4);
cv::Mat original = [MMOpenCVHelper cvMatFromUIImage:_adjustedImage];


cv::warpPerspective(original, undistorted, cv::getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst), cvSize(maxWidth, maxHeight));
```

Comment: I don't know much about this stuff from not having to ever do anything like this, but, do you know at what point of the code the image size changes? Are you able to test the size of the image before you change it to a UIImage again? Have you tested this with a smaller image, lets say a 10x10 image where you can do the math on paper before the code ?

Comment: What is the size of your image before you convert it to UIImage ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not resizing the image. It must be an unintended side effect of the  preprocessing which you don't detail here.

```
 UIImage* image = self.testImage;
 NSLog(@"original UIImage: %.0f %.0f", image.size.width,image.size.height);

 cv::Mat matImage = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];
 NSLog(@"cv matImage: %d %d", matImage.cols,matImage.rows);

 UIImage* newImage = [self UIImageFromCVMat:matImage];
 NSLog(@"new UIImage: %.0f %.0f", newImage.size.width,newImage.size.height);
```

> ```
> original UIImage: 720 960
>      cv matImage: 720 960
>      new UIImage: 720 960
> ```

*edit*
following your expanded question, it looks as if the output of `warpPerspective` is sized to `cvSize(maxWidth,maxHeight)` - so that is the size you will get. If you want to end up with the input size, you can `resize()`  before converting back to `UIImage`. Or simply set the output `mat` to the same size as the input.